# auto compile multiple text boxes using in one for loop vb 2008

Tags: vb.net

```
 `For i = 0 to 6
    textbox(i).Text = chr(65+i)
Next i`
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition.I am getting error in text box is type not use in expression.
I create one text box and copy & paste to 5 text boxes here not created to array format. Name is coming to textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,...etc,like this. I try to change the name is array format and not changed then the error  'property value is not valid ' is coming.
How to assume the name & create the code please tell me

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be some confusion about how many TextBoxes you have (5 or 7). The following code assumes you have 5, but can easily be modified.

```
Dim textBoxArray() as TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
For i = 0 to 4
    textBoxArray(i).Text = Chr(65 + i)
Next
```

Comment: Ya its running correctly. Thank you, thank u so much

Comment: Here one doubt please ex-plane me.  textBoxArray is name of the declaration  then how to work array format

Comment: What would you like explained? The code I posted creates an array that contains the 5 TextBoxes (TextBox1, TextBox2, and so on). Then it uses a corrected version of the code you posted to display a letter in each TextBox.

Comment: @Blackwood I suspect you meant to write "an array that contains references to the 5 TextBoxes..." - just to make it clear.

Comment: @Blackwood I create 5 textBoxes.Then i change the name is (Box1,Box2,Box3,Box4,Box5) .Now i declare                                           Dim bitBoxArray() As Box  = {Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5}                            'Box is not defined'  the error is coming

Comment: Changing the name of a TextBox from TextBox1 to Box1 Doesn't change the fact that it's type is still TextBox. You should code `Dim bitBoxArray() As TextBox = {Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4, Box5}`

Comment: Ok, This way is possible to Text box only or label r all other tools

Comment: You can create an array of any type of control. For example `Dim labelArray() as Label = {Label1, Label2, Label3}`